# Laravel create a dynamic schedule table

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a hospital table and schedule table, and i want to create a schedule table html using these table

```
+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |  hospital a  |
|  2 |  hospital b  |
+----+--------------+

+-----+---------+--------+---------------+
| day |  start  |   end  |  hospital_id  |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+
| mon |  10:00  |  14:00 |       1       |
| tue |  15:00  |  20:00 |       1       |
| wed |  14:00  |  19:00 |       2       |
| fri |  10:00  |  15:00 |       2       |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+
```

the problem is the schedule time didn't align to the correct `<th>`
What i need:

```
+-------+------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| mon   |  tue  |  wed  |  thu  |  fri  |  sat  |  sun |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                     hospital a                       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 10:00 | 15:00 |       |       |       |       |      |
|   -   |   -   |       |       |       |       |      |
| 14:00 | 20:00 |       |       |       |       |      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|                     hospital b                       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|       |       | 14:00 |       | 10:00 |       |      |
|       |       |   -   |       |   -   |       |      |
|       |       | 19:00 |       | 15:00 |       |      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

but it become like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| mon   |  tue  |  wed  |  thu  |  fri  |  sat  |  sun |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                     hospital a                       |
+-------+------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 10:00 | 15:00 |       |       |       |       |      |
|   -   |   -   |       |       |       |       |      |
| 14:00 | 20:00 |       |       |       |       |      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|                     hospital b                       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 14:00 | 10:00 |       |       |       |       |      |
|   -   |   -   |       |       |       |       |      |
| 19:00 | 15:00 |       |       |       |       |      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

this is my .blade.php script

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <td class="text-center">mon</td>
           <td class="text-center">tue</td>
           <td class="text-center">wed</td>
           <td class="text-center">thu</td>
           <td class="text-center">fri</td>
           <td class="text-center">sat</td>
           <td class="text-center">sun</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($hospital as $hos)
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center _b" colspan="7">{{$hos->name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        @foreach($schedule->where('hospital_id', $hos->id) as $sch)
        @if($sch->day == 'mon')
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                <div class="jam active">s/d</div>
                <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
            </td>
            @endif
            @if($sch->day == 'tue')
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                <div class="jam">s/d</div>
                <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
            </td>
            @endif
            @if($sch->day == 'wed')
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                <div class="jam">s/d</div>
                <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
            </td>
            @endif
            @if($sch->day == 'thu')
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                    <div class="jam">s/d</div>
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                </td>
                @endif
                @if($sch->day == 'fri')
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                    <div class="jam">s/d</div>
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                </td>
                @endif
                @if($sch->day == 'sat')
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                    <div class="jam active">s/d</div>
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                </td>
                @endif
                @if($sch->day == 'sun')
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                    <div class="jam">s/d</div>
                    <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
                </td>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</table>
```

this is happen because the `<td></td>` will not created when the `if` condition doesn't meet. but when I try to move `if` inside the `td` the table looks more terrible

Comment: Have you tried to create empty td id if condition doesn't meet?

Comment: already tried that, and the table looks more weird. Before adding empty `<td>` [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/Tw4hcoC.png). After adding empty `<td>` [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/U4vkJtN.png)

Comment: you will always have to add all tds, just fill those tds where you need to show data based on condition

Comment: use the for loop instead, create all the tds , and use if inside each td, so if the condition is meet u get the data & if not it stays empty and keep the form aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output an empty `<td></td>` should that day doesn't have any time.

```
<?php
    $days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];   
?>

@foreach($schedule->where('hospital_id', $hos->id) as $sch)
    @foreach($days as $day)
      @if($sch->day == $day)
         <td class="text-center">
            <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->start_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
            <div class="jam active">s/d</div>
            <div class="jam">{{Carbon::parse($sch->end_time)->format('H:i')}}</div>
         </td>
      @else
         <td></td>
      @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```